# What is the meaning of $dA$ in double integrals?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

What is the meaning of $dA$ in $\iint_E\dots dA$, where $E$ is a region in the $xy$ plane?

In some integrals   we use $dA=dx\,dy$, but in others $dA=\hat{k}\,dx\,dy$. (Here $\hat {k}$ is the unit vector in the $z$ direction.)

Why this difference? Also, is there a general formula for $dA$?

Comment: dA is a symbol that is generally used to denote a surface element. It can optionally have a direction, which is then perpendicular to the surface element. In e.g. polar coordinates it would be $dA=r d\theta dr$.

Comment: I edited the question to put notation into  context, and to bring it closer to the existing answer.

Comment: @IlikeSerena I understand!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY Ok!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider a vector field $\mathbf v$. Say we want to compute the flux through some oriented surface $\mathcal S$. What will our flux integral look like? $$\iint_\mathcal{S} \ldots $$
Well, our vector field will be like a weight function by which we integrate our surface. We accomplish this with the inner product $\mathbf v \cdot \hat{\mathbf N} \mathrm{dA}$, where $\hat{\mathbf N}$ is normal to the surface and $\mathrm{dA}$ is the surface area element.

In this case one could choose the notation $\mathrm d \mathbf A = \hat{\mathbf N} \,\mathrm{dA}$, to mean the *vector surface area element*.

So, we need to distinguish a *surface area element* $\mathrm{dA}$, which could be $\mathrm{dx\,dy}$, from a *vector surface area element* $\mathrm{d \mathbf A}$, which has an orientation.

Comment: Ahaa... I got it!!! Thank you!!! :-)